# How to use code to add jpanel to jframe in netbean 8.0.2

Tags: java, jframe, netbeans-8

I have some code like this:

```
private void formWindowOpened(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {                                  

        // create header panel
        JPanel hPanel = new JPanel();
        hPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout(600, 100));
        this.getContentPane().add(hPanel);

        // text header
        JLabel hLabel = new JLabel("LỊCH VẠN NIÊN 2015");
        hPanel.add(hLabel);

    }
```

I create a form has with and height are 600px and 400px. I want to add a panel (600x100) include a text has center vertical and center horizontal. I try code above but my frame is blank. Please help me, I'm a newbie :)

Comment: It is not a problem of netbean

Comment: I agree but do you know how to do it with java swing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
hPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout(600, 100));
```

That means gap between compponents is 600 (horizontal) and 100 (vertical). Nothing related to size.

Try `setPreferredSize()` instead but it's not recommended. It's better to reflect sizes of componnets rather than define your own.

Also move the

```
this.getContentPane().add(hPanel);
```

to the method end to be the last statement.

You may also need to call pack() or setSize() of the frame.